# Print Pascal's Triangle using only limited programming concepts

Tags: python, pascals-triangle

Please tell me what is wrong with my program. I want to print Pascal's Triangle using only nested loops and `if` statements because these have been covered in our course:

```
x=int(input("Enter depth of triangle "))
y=0
n=1
while(y<=x):
    a=11**y
    z=a
    za=0
    b=z%10
    z=z//10
    if(y==0):
        print(x*" ",b)
    elif(y!=0):
        if(za==0):
            print(x*" ",b,end="")
        elif(za<x):
            print((x-za)*" ",b,end=" ")
        elif(za==x):
            print((x-za)*" ",b)
    y=y+1
    za=za+1
    else:
    print("program done")
```

Output:

```
Enter depth of triangle 4
     1
     1     1     1     1program done
```

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: The indentation shown in the question can’t possibly match a working program. Please edit it to reflect what you actually have.

Comment: sorry that i didnt' enter proper indentation . i fixed it now. pls check now. the output doesn't come as i want it to be .@R

Comment: Please make a [mre]. Whittle your code down to just the part you're having a problem with, and explain what the problem is in the question.

Comment: It’s still not fixed, sorry. If you can’t seem to get it to look right, a screenshot is an option.

Comment: Ill try and fix it by tomorrow guys. Its night time where I live , so I'll fix it by tomorrow. Sorry for the inconveniences caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [Calculating a row or diagonal by itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself) section of the Wikipedia article on Pascal's Triangle, getting the numbers just using nested `while` loops (no `if`s) seems fairly straight forward:

```
depth = int(input("Enter depth of triangle: "))

row = 0

while row < depth:
    number = 1
    denominator = 1
    numerator = row

    print(number, end=' ')

    while numerator > 0:
        number = number * numerator // denominator
        print(number, end=' ')
        numerator = numerator - 1
        denominator = denominator + 1

    print()
    row = row + 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
Enter depth of triangle: 10
1 
1 1 
1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
1 4 6 4 1 
1 5 10 10 5 1 
1 6 15 20 15 6 1 
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1 
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1 
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1 
>
```

Now add the necessary code to reshape the output from a right triange into more of an  isosceles triangle.

> Please tell me what is wrong with my program.

You say that you want to solve the problem using nested loops but you don't actually have nested loops -- just a single outer loop.  Going from rows of the triangle to powers of 11 is simple, given some addition carry logic, but going the other way 'round seems a difficult way to go about this:

```
a=11**y
```

And you should pick better variable names.

Comment: thanks man . appreciate the help. i didnt see your comment. but i figured out the a=11**y thing . and yea the variables name seem a bit too tough to properly name lol. thanks for the advice.